# Is it possible to take app's comments from AppStore with any language to show it on web site

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, app-store

I made some research but could not find something  yet, i think Apple won't let it but i need to ask it, if is it possible to take my app's comments from AppStore with any language to show it on web site. If i'm asking this question in wrong place and wrong tags please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Download the page and scrape it out. Any language will work for this. Here is how to do it in PHP:

```
<?php
$url = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/temple-run/id420009108?mt=8";

echo '<style>.author {font-size:small; color:gray} </style>';
echo '<p>Reading URL [ '. $url. ' ] ...';
$str = file_get_contents($url);

echo '<p>Parsing ...';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="customer-reviews"]//span[@class="customerReviewTitle"] | //div[@class="customer-reviews"]//span[@class="user-info"] | //div[@class="customer-reviews"]//p[@class="content"]');
$str_out='';
$n=0;

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $this_line=trim($tag->nodeValue);
    if(empty($this_line)) continue; 
    switch($n % 3) {
    case 0: $str_out.='<h3>'. $this_line. '</h3>'; break;
    case 1: $str_out.='<p class=author>'. $this_line. '</p>'; break;
    case 2: $str_out.='<p>'. $this_line. '</p>'; break;
    }
    $n++;
}


echo '<p>Displaying results ...'. "\n". $str_out;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible. Just use your language of choice to crawl Apple's site and retrieve the comments. Then format them and display it on your site.

I'm not sure how to go about this in PHP. But for ASP.NET take a look at the [HttpWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).